# My home folder opens up Photo Booth when clicked on

Tags: finder, unix

For some reason when the icon for the home folder is clicked it opens up photo booth. I changed what application it uses and the finder stays open.

I tried fixing permissions and checking the hard drive in the recovery boot to no avail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The home folder somehow got changed to type "package." I figured out how to change it back to folder and it's opening up in the Finder again.

Comment: Could you please document *how* you found out about the change and what you did to change it back? This would help other users with the same issue sometime in the future.

Comment: I plan on it but I answered it when I was on the train this morning. Kinda hard to post reference on a mobile browser